# Expansion vs Decreasing $d$-neighborhood min-cut

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we're given a graph $G$, in which know for (almost) any node-pair, their $d$-neighborhood min-cut (i.e. min-cut defined on their $d$-neighborhood subgraph) is decreasing with $d$.
Is there any way to prove that this graph has a low expansion? (or find upper/lower bounds for the expansion)

Comment: Can you give a definition of $d$-neighborhood? Is it $\{z:\text{dist}(x,z)\leq d\}\cup\{z:\text{dist}(y,z)\leq d\}$?

Comment: Yeah that sounds right to me.